# Call to a Construct

Tags: php, class, construct

I have a class.php with a construct

```
<?php
class Fruit {
  public $name;
  public $color;

  function __construct($name, $color) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->color = $color;
  }
  function get_name() {
    return $this->name;
  }
  function get_color() {
    return $this->color;
  }
}
```

In other file when i want call this
in this ways works:

```
$apple1 = new Fruit("Apple", "red");
$apple2 = new Fruit("Apple", "yellow");
```

but i need call something :

```
$apple1 = new Fruit($name1, $color1);
$apple2 = new Fruit($name2, $color2);


$name1='Apple';
$color1= get_user_meta($user_id, 'color', true);
$name2='Apple';
$color2='yellow';
```

All this appears like undefined. I saw this isnt the correct way, but how i can do?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Did you set the values of `$name1, $color1` and `$name2, $color2` Before using them on a call to instantiate the new object

Comment: Cannot Reproduce: Unless you are doing things in the order you show in the question, which is obviously the wrong order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a `__construct` by variables but for that you must specify them before you 
creating new object.

**Change your code to**

```
$name1='Apple';
$name2='Apple';
$color2='yellow';
$apple1 = new Fruit($name1, $color1);
$apple2 = new Fruit($name2, $color2);
$color1= get_user_meta($user_id, 'color', true);
```